Random subsets of measure spaces
Related to generalizing reliability polynomials from graph theory to other spaces I ran into the following question.
To start, take a finite set $M$ and build a subset $X$ of $M$ at random by including elements of $M$ independently with some probability $\lambda\in[0,1]$. If $\#(A)$ denotes the number of elements of a set $A$ then we would have the probability
\begin{align}
P(X=A)=\lambda^{\#(A)}(1-\lambda)^{\#(M)-\#(A)}
\end{align}
Viewing $\mu:A\mapsto \#(A)$ as a measure on $M$, can this generalize to building random subsets of arbitrary measure spaces?
What I mean is can we construct some random variable $X=X(\omega)$ with values in $\mu$-measurable sets of a measure space $M$ where the events $X=A, X\subseteq A, \mu(X)\leq x$ and etc. are measurable and their probabilities are functions of only the measure of $A$, the parameter $\lambda$, and $x$? We of course want properties similar to the finite case.
Small values of $\lambda$ should make it more probable that the measure of $X$ is small, and vice versa for large values of $\lambda$. Like if this makes any intuitive sense, if $\lambda=0$ then almost surely $X$ has measure $0$ and if $\lambda=1$ then almost surely $X$ has full measure.
What properties should the probabilities $P(X\subseteq A)$ satisfy? Increasing $\lambda$ should lead to larger $X$, thereby decreasing the chance that $X$ is contained in some fixed $A$.
Can we meaningfully enforce something like
\begin{align}
P(X=A)=\lambda^{\mu(A)}(1-\lambda)^{\mu(M)-\mu(A)}
\end{align}
for all measurable $A$? I feel no, since for $M$ of interest we will have $P(X=A)=0$ for all but countably many $A$.
Something like "If I generate a subset of the unit interval $[0,1]$ uniformly, whatever the hell that means, the chance I end specifically with the interval $[0,1/2]$ is zero." feels right to me.
Is this somehow related to random measures and the Poisson point process, like a Poisson point process can be viewed as generating a random multisubset of $M$.
If what I'm getting at already has a name or something like this has been done before, I'd love a reference.

As you say, I think you might be looking for a Poisson process on your measure space. You need some mild niceness condition e.g. the measure is a Borel measure on a complete metric space; it should also be locally finite (every point is contained in a finite measure neighbourhood) and $\sigma$-finite. Then you can build a random variable $X$ taking values in the set of countable subsets of $M$, with the property that $\mathbb P(#(X\cap A))$ is Poisson with parameter $m(A)$ for each $A$ such that $m(A)<\infty$; and if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $X\cap A$ and $X\cap B$ are independent.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#General_Poisson_point_process for example.

A PPP wouldn't fit with what I'm looking for. Especially the comment about the generated set X almost surely having full measure if $\lambda=1$.
